# Get plain text from QLineEdit

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4, qstring, qlineedit

I want to retrieve plain text from `QLineEdit()` object. The text method returns a `QString` object. I just want a simple string object.
I am using pyqt4.

```
def n(self):
    new_label=QLineEdit()
    new_label.setText("txt")
    txt=self.new_label.text()
    self.name=txt
```

txt should be a simple string not `QString`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert *one* QString in **Python 2**, do this:

```
    self.name = unicode(self.new_label.text())
```

To automatically convert *all* QStrings, put this at the beginning of your code:

```
import sip
sip.setapi('QString', 2)
# must be before any pyqt imports

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
```

If you do this, there's no need to keep using `unicode()`, because *all* methods will return python strings instead of QStrings. And note that with **Python 3**, this behaviour is the default, so you would not need to do anything to always get python strings.

Answer (score 1):

Convert to string with:

```
self.name = str(txt)
```